# How do I find a child given two parent_ids in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child

I am not entirely sure how to word this question, but here goes:

I am trying to find all entries in a table given two parent variables.

So,

```
father has_many :children
mother has_many :children
child belongs_to :father
child belongs_to :mother
```

Now, how might I find all children based on a specific father and mother?

If I left out important information, please let me know. Otherwise, I greatly appreciate any help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Child.find_all_by_father_id_and_mother_id(father.id, mother_id)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be find_all or something like that to give more than one common children?

Comment: Right you are Mr @natedavisolds. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was stumped for so long! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways:

```
@children = Child.where(:mother_id => mother.id, :father_id => father.id).all
```

or if you've already loaded the children:

```
@children = mother.children & father.children
```

Comment: @Ryan - no I meant the children.  We are all assuming that the parents have been loaded, but this is only better if :include => :children was part of the scope.